# How do I write an API that makes use of many smaller APIs?

Tags: design-patterns, javascript, api-design

I have a solid set of classes that do the following

- build tables from data and templates
- advanced form serialization
- build forms from data and templates
- launch overlays with forms/wizards
- short poll for new data
- post data
  ..etc

Basically a lot of little classes and modules that work independently. Now I want to write a slightly more involved class that involves them all. This would be a table that in reality is simply managing a database table. Thus it can add/edit/delete rows, automatically update, and so on.

I have all of the components required - all extremely separated and unique - but I don't know how to put them together. This is a consistent place where I fail in programming. I begin to start essentially wrapping each smaller class's functions into a massive class, because the user needs access to these useful functions. Does this make sense? Is an API really just a huge wrapper for all your components?

Comment: You might have a look at the [Facade design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)

Comment: You might google for "javascript module". Modules are for bundling classes & functions to bigger components. You can typically control which parts you want to see in the public API, and which parts you want to keep internally.